# CSS keyframe animation not working on floated element

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Hi I am building a simple slider to present a project.

The slider is based on [swipe.js.org](https://www.swipe.js.org). I am doing everything as I should, except one thing: While every slide div contains only one image, one slide contains 2 overlapping images #img7-1 & #img7-2. I am overlaying those two images to fade the opacity of the upper image.

Below is my css. The order of elements represents the structure of the elements in the DOM.
I also have a link to the presentation at the end if you just want to look at the page source.

```
.swipe {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.swipe-wrap > div img {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
 }

#img7-1{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#img7-2{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
animation: fade 1.5 ease-in-out 1.5s alternate infinite running;
}
@keyframes fade{
  from {opacity: 0%;}
  to {opacity: 100%;}
}
```

You can view the presentation [here](https://hedinger-design.com/rivalt.html), all the code, styles & js (except cdn library) is on that html page.

If anyone knows this, please help me - coding is not my best skill.
Thanks everyone.

Edit:
div elements affected in dom:

```
<div class="swipe-wrap">
  <div>
    <img id="img7-1" src="/images/rivian/Rivian_Storyboards-7-1.jpg">
    <img id="img7-2" src="/images/rivian/Rivian_Storyboards-7-2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not refer us to external websites for a reproducible version of your problem - a [mre] of it belongs directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code through the CSS validator and it came back saying your shorthand notation for animation was incorrect so this fixed that problem. My next question is what is #img7-2 referring to in your html? I don't see what this animation is being used on in your source code.

EDITED:
Once you add top:0 to the img7-2 you can now see the effect happening, before the image was placed outside the browser window. You can change the timing however you'd like.

```
#img7-2 {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
/*animation: overlay 6s ease-in-out infinite running;*/
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-delay: 1.5s;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-play-state: running;
top:0
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. 

Those two ID‘s refer to the 2 image tags contained in the 8th slide div. Visually they overlay each other so you can only see 1 at a time if the animation isnt going.

Sorry I cant give you proper code right now, I‘m on a mobile phone, but will update as soon as i get back to a computer (ca 45-50min)

Comment: ok, so here we go: 

there is an element called <div class="swipe-wrap"> - inside it amongst some others are the following:

    <div><img id="img7-1" src="/images/rivian/Rivian_Storyboards-7-1.jpg"><img id="img7-2" src="/images/rivian/Rivian_Storyboards-7-2.jpg"></div>

it can be a little confusing as this is the source code, but the script changes the html, so when you look at it in the inspector after render, there will be additional attributes and values to many of the elements.

Comment: hey, I accidentally edited your answer, adding in the affected img tags. sorry about that, my bad.

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thank you so much! Can I venmo you something for your troubles - what's your account name?